# Dynamic High Charts in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am trying to create a dynamic highchart in a new angular 4 project. Currently I am trying to inject a service into my component that holds the dynamic data that will be used in the highchart. This data is passed as an array. I am using https://github.com/cebor/angular-highcharts/blob/4/README.md for an angular wrapped version of highcharts.

I am able to get a highchart working when it is hard coded with a data set, but I am having trouble passing in the dynamic data from my service. My component.ts file currently looks like

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SiteService } from '../../site.service';
import { Chart } from 'angular-highcharts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})
export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public siteService:SiteService) {
    this.stales = this.siteService.stales;
    console.log(this.stales);
  }

  stales:number[] = [];
  testvar:number = 0;

/***************************************************/


chart = new Chart({
      chart: {
        type: 'line'
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Linechart'
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
      series: [{
        name: 'Line 1',
        data: this.stales 
//this is where I am trying to use the array from the injected service as a //variable but I am getting no output
      }]
    });

  log() {
    console.log(this.stales);
    this.chart.addPoint(this.testvar);
  }



/***********************************************/
  ngOnInit() {
    this.stales = this.siteService.stales;
    this.testvar = this.stales[3];
    console.log(this.testvar);
    console.log(this.stales);
  }

/************************************************/


}
```

Whenever I log my this.stales variable it all appears to be correct. Logging a random index of my array returns the correct value as well. I have also tried to replicate the same functionality using charts.js but run into the same issue so I believe that this is due to me having a lack of angular knowledge. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Highcharts part seems to be working fine, but if you have any problem with Highcharts then please describe it. Maybe the data is loaded after chart is created, so at the time of chart building the data is missing? In that case you should build chart after data is provided.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    @Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css'],
  providers: [ SiteService ] // add this as a provider
})
```